# Tag GTM in body

Tags: php, html, google-tag-manager

My tag GTM in the body is not properly installed because outside the body section. I'm very new in coding, so I'm sorry for this question but how to insert the code noscript correctly in body section ?

Thanks a lot

Here the code :

```
    <body<?php body_class( mk_get_body_class( global_get_post_id() ) ); ?> <?php echo get_schema_markup( 'body' ); ?> data-adminbar="<?php echo is_admin_bar_showing(); ?>">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5DB5QN9"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <?php
        // Hook when you need to add content right after body opening tag. to be used in child themes or customisations.
        do_action( 'theme_after_body_tag_start' );
    ?>

    <!-- Target for scroll anchors to achieve native browser bahaviour + possible enhancements like smooth scrolling -->
    <div id="top-of-page"></div>

        <div id="mk-boxed-layout">

            <div id="mk-theme-container" <?php echo is_header_transparent( 'class="trans-header"' ); ?>>

                <?php
                mk_get_header_view( 'styles', 'header-' . get_header_style() );
```

Answer (score 0):

That appears to only contain the fallback GTM code for users without JavaScript. You should have an additional JavaScript snipped to place on your page that's completely missing from the above example?

See their documentation here for reference (you're missing section #1):
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart